# How to get this file prompted to the user?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-conversion

Hi Im working on a **MVC3 Razor project** and I have been stuck on this problem for a few hours now...

I'm trying to get a html to pdf converter to serve a document to the user...

What I want is the following..

A page is rendered and displayed. On the bottom of the page there should be a little icon display something like download as pdf. and what that does is where my problem lies..

All the data that I want is dynamically created within a `$("#content").html();`

So what I have tried is a jquery/ajax function passing `$("#content").html();` as a paramater to my function which creates the pdf (works but I have no clue how to prompt the created file to the user?)

Other solution was `@(Html.ActionLink())` but I dont know how to pass the data `($("#content").html())` within that link?

And when trying to work with the functionallity to use the converter to go to the url was a dead end cuz it got its own session and got redirected to the loginpage..

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround, what I did was write an extension to my HtmlHelper and use that to render my control into a html string instead of a view. Therefor I could use a actionlink to say render this page and get all the html data that way.

http://msug.vn.ua/Posts/Details/3301

Thanks for help tho!

Answer (score 0):

Why just create a function that returns the created PDF (during ajax request) as File result and then set the window's location to point to this action once the ajax request is completed successfully?

Edit: That means you are not saving the PDF anywhere. So the workaround, is to either use this [jquery download plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/) or append an iframe dynamically and then post the data through it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm sounds reasonable, but how would I do that? I mean I use jquery to pass the data, the file is created within the function but then its stuck there(i'd hoped to not have to save the file locally).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JavaScript, but what if you save the PDF in the temp file first by calling you web service method, and then after it completed you can use JavaScript to navigate to the URL where generated PDF will be returned as content.

Comment: Thought of this but keeping it as a last option because I'd rather not store files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `XmlHTTPRequest` Object cannot handle datatypes other than `html`, `text`, `json`, `jsonp` and `xml` you will need to redirect to the pdf location.

I'm not sure what exactly you're doing in your Ajax Request, but once that is completed you can just redirect the window(Form-Action) to the location of the created PDF. This wouldn't actually redirect the browser but only prompt for saving the file.

Comment: $("#getPDF").click(function () {
               var data = $(".page").html();
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("getPDF", "Core")',
                   data: "data=" + data,
                   async: false,
                   success: function (data) {
                   
                   }
               });
           });

Comment: my main hope was to be able to put the file in the response headers and serve it so. But that is only avaiable through the actionlink, and then I dont know how to pass the data.

Comment: You can just try doing `window.open('Controller/Action/')`. This would load the prompt for or load the pdf in that window/tab. Just a suggestion.. if that helps your scenario.